# jquery to get id of button inside td of known tr

Tags: jquery, html, select, button, html-table

How do I get the id of a button inside a dataTable table, when the only info I have is which tr contains the td that has the button. There is more than one td and the button may not be the first one. The button id that I require is ".delete_email", note, there may be more than one with the same class name.

I have tried:

```
 var id = $('#view_all_emails1').DataTable().$('tr.selected td:nth-child(5) button[".delete_email"]').attr("id");
```

But this causes an error:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: tr.selected td:nth-child(5) button[".delete_email"]

The html:

```
 <tr>
      <td>Wed 13-07-16</td>
      <td><a href="mailto:?????@?????.???.??">????????</a></td>
      <td><a href="index.php?a=em&id=5&ebox=1&et=1"  onClick="OpenEmail(5); return false;">
      <div class="visible-lg hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="color:#06F;">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!</div>
      <div class="visible-md hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="color:#06F;">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!</div>
      <div class="visible-sm hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-xs" style="color:#06F;">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!</div>
      <div class="visible-xs hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" style="color:#06F;">The quick brown fox<br />jumps over the lazy<br />dog! </div></a></td>
      <td>enquiries</td>
      <td><span class="octicon octicon-mail-read" title="Read!"></span></td>
      <td>
      <input type='hidden' id='this_id' name='this_id' value='5'/><input type='hidden' id='et' name='et' value='1'/><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" id="4:5" name="delete_email" class="delete_email btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Delete this email!"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></span></td>
      <td>2.1<small>kb</small></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: `button[".delete_email"]` should be `button.delete_email` since `delete_email` is a class

Comment: `$("tr.selected button.delete_email").attr("id")`

Comment: it's a class or a name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need to go through DataTable API to get this value.

```
var id = $('#view_all_emails1 tr.selected .delete_email').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not this way?

'delete_email' as a name

```
var id = $('#view_all_emails1 tr.selected input button[name="delete_email"]').attr('id');
```

or

'delete_email' as class

```
var id = $('#view_all_emails1 tr.selected input button.delete_email').attr('id');
```